# Add item to input programmatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, tagging, selectize.js

[Selectize.js](http://brianreavis.github.io/selectize.js/) allows to transform inputs into widgets with tagging, auto-complete etc.. I'm trying to add tag into input using code.

Here's what I have so far.

```
$(function() {
    $("#tags").selectize({
        create: true
    })

    var selectize_tags = $("#tags")[0].selectize
    selectize_tags.createItem("foo")
    selectize_tags.refreshItems()
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qDL37/

Unfortunately, “foobar“ isn't added to input box. As far as I know, it's [the correct way](https://github.com/brianreavis/selectize.js/blob/master/docs/api.md#methods_items) to do it.

Could this be a bug in selectize.js? I tried to search through GitHub issues, but couldn't find anything like that.

Also I tried to read code of selectize.js, but no luck.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Thanks to great people from #javascript @freenode, this is the correct way.

```
$(function() {
    $("#tags").selectize({
        create: true
    })

    var selectize_tags = $("#tags")[0].selectize
    selectize_tags.addOption({
        text:'Foo',
        value: 'foo'
    });
    selectize_tags.addItem('foo')
    // selectize_tags.refreshItems()
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qDL37/1/

Comment: I am having the same issue, but I am using the `valueField, labelField, searchField` option .  Do you have a solution for that ?

Comment: @Fabrizio My guess would be to change `text` and `value` keys to values you have specified [for `labelField` and `valueField`](https://github.com/brianreavis/selectize.js/blob/master/docs/usage.md#data_searching).

Comment: spent 2 hours looking for that, this topic was at the bottom of google searc results. thanks, it works!!!